# Docker execute MySQL query on start-up and output results

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

looking for some advice with creating a homebrew, primitive version of AWS Datapipeline with extra steps.

I'm wanting to create a Docker image with PHP and MySQL client installed.
On start-up I'd like to run a MySQL query on another (remote) server and then parse the output of the query to another file.

1. Start container with a MySQL query.
2. Container connects to remote server.
3. Run MySQL query that was sent in using the connected server.
4. Query result output to file for further processing by a PHP script.
5. PHP script reads file output and transforms the data.
6. Transformed data is then uploaded to a FTP server.

I don't need the assistance with steps 5 and 6 just getting the docker to start and connect to remote server to run a query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't the best question for Stackoverflow.  Generally you have to provide some more details in order for people to make the effort to help you and generally then only with a very specific point.  Especially for a task like this that should be very common.  If you provided a dockerfile or setup with logs and most of what you've tried already except for the one tiny piece you're missing (like the connection at step 5) then you may get better help than a general "howto" question like this.  See the Stackoverflow FAQ for more info on how to ask better questions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will post what I currently have an see if anyone can help correct what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using official mysql docker image then

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions `**.sh, .sql and .sql.gz**` that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
> dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
> data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
> by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Here is example, you can even run custom shell scripts, with shared volume your php container can easily access file generated.

```
version : '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./scripts/add-my-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
      - "./scripts/add-data-to-it.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql"
      - "./scripts/generate-some-output.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/process.sh"
```

Here is reference to https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L56

It contains

```
# usage: docker_process_init_files [file [file [...]]]
#    ie: docker_process_init_files /always-initdb.d/*
# process initializer files, based on file extensions
docker_process_init_files() {
    # mysql here for backwards compatibility "${mysql[@]}"
    mysql=( docker_process_sql )

    echo
    local f
    for f; do
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)
                # https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/450#issuecomment-393167936
                # https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/452
                if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                    mysql_note "$0: running $f"
                    "$f"
                else
                    mysql_note "$0: sourcing $f"
                    . "$f"
                fi
                ;;
            *.sql)    mysql_note "$0: running $f"; docker_process_sql < "$f"; echo ;;
            *.sql.gz) mysql_note "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | docker_process_sql; echo ;;
            *.sql.xz) mysql_note "$0: running $f"; xzcat "$f" | docker_process_sql; echo ;;
            *)        mysql_warn "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
        esac
        echo
    done
}
```