# How can I initialize a database with some tables in a container using docker compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have my db service:

```yaml
...
mysql-server:
    container_name: silos-database
    init: true
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${USER_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - target: 3036
        published: 3036
    networks:
      - backend-net
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: db_vol
        target: /var/lib/mysql
...
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:latest
```

The `init.sql` file contain same tables that my database must have

```sql
...
-- users data
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  email VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
  -- password is SHA256 hashed, so 64 characters
  password CHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions (
  email VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
  token TEXT NOT NULL,
  expireDate BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
...
```

How can I build a service with the content of `init.sql` file already inside the service?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691186/docker-execute-mysql-query-on-start-up-and-output-results/67691350#67691350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add `init.sql` file to Your docker image:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

If You want to provide `init.sql` during container start instead of build time, You can mount directory containing `init.sql` into container:

```
mysql-server:
    container_name: silos-database
    init: true
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${USER_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - target: 3036
        published: 3036
    networks:
      - backend-net
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: db_vol
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - /local/path/with/initsql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: This answer is correct. And it's better if you don't recreate the Docker Image. Just use the official mysql docker image and mount the `sql`, `sql.gz` or `sh` extension file into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. You can also check MySQL Docker official documentation as well (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)